# Beginner question: Accessing functions.php through admin web interface in order to import custom post types?

Tags: custom-post-types, functions, import

Is it possible to access the functions.php file just by using the admin web interface? I'm trying to access previously created (manually coded) custom post types and I'm having to jump through a lot of hoops because I can't access the code in the functions.php file.

I've looked through a number of help pages, but the steps suggested always seem to involve the functions.php file (which I can't access) or the use of import/export tools from the plugin that created the custom post types in the first place (and no plugin was used as far as I can tell).

This seems like a really basic issue, but I can't figure it out for the life of me. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can't you edit it via Design > Editor?

Comment: I'm just using the web interface with an admin account, and I don't see any menus called "Design". Are those instructions intended for a downloadable wordpress management software?

Comment: Could be "theme", I just looked it up in a German locale. It is the point where you can add themes, manage widgets. There should be a navigation point called "editor"

Comment: There's an "Appearance" tab, which has a "Theme" sub-tab (url ends with "/wp-admin/themes.php") with the options "Customize","Widgets","Menus","Background", and "Theme Check" (from a plug-in). The Customize tab sounds like it's the closest to what you're referring to, but it just brings me to the page that allows for customization of basic site-wide graphical elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is sometimes possible to edit theme files, including `functions.php`, inside wp-admin. Many hosts and devs disable this feature since it can cause security issues as well as allow you to break the site. So if you can access the file via FTP, that's generally the recommended method.

If you don't see ["Appearance > Editor"](https://codex.wordpress.org/Appearance_Editor_Screen) in your admin menu, either you don't have permission to edit files (a role/capability issue), or else the feature has been disabled.

You can check your `wp-config.php` file and see if it has been disabled here - if it has, you'll see `define('DISALLOW_FILE_EDIT', true);`. Though if you can access wp-config, you should also be able to access theme files. :) If this is not the case, check with your host to see whether they have disabled file editing in the admin area and to find out whether they can enable it for your site.

Comment: Yeah, the wp-config.php fix is a real Catch 22. It seems the editor has been disabled. My user account is admin, so it seems likely that it's a hosting issue, as you say. What exactly do you mean by "access the file via FTP"? Is that just following [these steps](https://codex.wordpress.org/Installing_WordPress)?

Comment: Not exactly. FTP is a type of software that lets you connect directly to the web server, download files, and upload files. So you connect, download the file, edit in your favorite text editor, and then go back to the FTP client to upload it. Your host should provide login credentials. Or, if this is above your head, your host may be willing to edit your `wp-config.php` file for you if that is indeed what is disabling admin access to edit files. So no matter what the case - contacting your host is the next step.

Comment: Yeah, I suppose the credentials for using FTP are unrelated to the credentials used for gaining access to the web interface. Thanks, I'll try contacting the host.